# My default controller does not work (.Net MVC)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, default

I work on an mvc application (.Net MVC 3).

I would like to achieve that if the user leaves the url-path (e.g. `http://localhost:12345/`), a default controller is called to output a default view. So I registered this in Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Route1", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Default", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
}
```

I have a DefaultController in the folder "Controllers"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace RyfMvcTestApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : Controller
    {
      public ActionResult Default()
      {
        return View();
      }
    }
}
```

The view (Default.cshtml) is found in Views/Default and just shows a welcome message.
Unfortunately, if I leave the url-path, **a blank page is shown**. It only works if I add "Default" as path to the url

```
http://localhost:12345/Default
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: No I think you are doing fine! One thing though I assume you don't have any more routes defined in Global.asax If that is the case, then please add your Default route as the first route !

Comment: No, that´s the complete code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry everyone, I made a very stupid mistake, by inserting a Default.aspx page into the project. By default, this page is always displayed when the url contains no path, and it has priority over the settings of the global.asax :(

Comment: Good you found out the error ! Since finding such errors make you a bit frustrated always ..

Comment: Yes... especially because I should have known since asking another question on SO...

Answer (score 4):

Unable to reproduce your issue. Steps:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application using the built-in wizard
2. Right click on the Controllers folder, select Add->Controller and use `DefaultController` as name with the following contents:

   ```
   public class DefaultController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Default()
       {
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add a `~/Views/Default/Default.cshtml` view:

   ```
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Default";
       Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   <h2>Default</h2>
   ```
4. Update the RegisterRoutes method in Global.asax so that it look like this:

   ```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
           "Route1",
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           new { controller = "Default", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
   }
   ```
5. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>
6. The built-in web server is started, the application runs in the default browser using `http://localhost:xxxx/` as url and the `default` action is executed on the `default` controller.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see your point. You're trying to achieve something that is already built-in and ready to use in any fresh mvc project.

When you create a new project, there's a default route using controller = "home", action = "index" and that just works as you intend.

Maybe it's the fact that you named both the controller and the action the same (Default) but I really don't know, nor see the point to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from this [page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs):

> If you don't supply a controller, then the controller parameter defaults to the value Home. If you don't supply an action, the action parameter defaults to the value Index. Finally, if you don't supply an id, the id parameter defaults to an empty string.

So you can rename your controller to `HomeContoller` or you can create a redirect to your desired URl inside `default.aspx` file.

Comment: Your answer does not seem to be correct ! I mean the user can make any controller as default and any action as default. There is nothing like it has to be Home controller. In the link you have given, it just explains the behavior with respect to the example!